# Write enum values to MySQL table using Node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, enums

I'm writing a REST API server in Node.js. I have a table in MySQL that one of it's columns defined as Enum.
How can I write the value I get from POST request to the DB as **Enum value**?

For example, I have a users table:

```
email - varchar(100)
relationshipStatus - ENUM('single','married','divorced','widow')
```

And the post request is:

```
{
  "email": "bla@gmail.com",
  "status": "single"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use just string value for your enum as stated in MySQL example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE shirts (
    name VARCHAR(40),
    size ENUM('x-small', 'small', 'medium', 'large', 'x-large')
);
INSERT INTO shirts (name, size) VALUES ('dress shirt','large'), ('t-shirt','medium'),
  ('polo shirt','small');
```

See more details [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/enum.html#enum-literals)